# Tension in the string produced due to pulling vs pushing

Tags: forces, terminology, string

I know that tension is produced when we pull the rope, but what if we push it? What would that be called? Is that tension too? Negative tension?

Comment: Notice that $\text{pull}= (-)\text{push}$

Comment: You just described the feeling I occasionally get when trying to teach high school physics to students who have poor study habits ... I feel like I am pushing a rope uphill!

Comment: Compression but pretty hard to compress a non rigid object

Answer (score 1):

When you push a rope, it has that bulk property to easily change its shape and bend without producing much of a reaction force. But if you pack the rope in a very narrow hollow cylinder (an impossible ideal case indeed) where the rope won't have the freedom to bend, and then push it, it will get compressed first filling up gaps in the fiber binding but after a limit it will surely produce a restoring force when the molecules will feel that other molecules are coming closer than the permissible limit, hence increasing the molecular potential energy (just like tension acts when the molecules feel that their neighbors are going too far, hence increasing the potential energy). It's up to you if you want to call this tension. Of course its better observed if you try to squeeze a bar or something solid, but ignoring the gaps in the fiber and the fiber flexibility, it's fundamentally the same thing.